# How do I set the content for a post of a particular CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, the-content

I have a CPT called Contest.  When a contest is created or updated, I want to manually set the value of the post content to my shortcode from my plugin.  I have custom metaboxes that I use with this CPT, so the content of the post will be based on the values of those metaboxes.  I have tried `add_filter('the_content', 'my_content')` but no changes are made to the post_content column in the database.  What am I doing wrong?

> Note:  I used `wp_die()` to see if the filter was even being called, and
>   `wp_die()` didn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
function imgw_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box( 'contest-dates', __('Running Dates'), 'imgw_dates_metabox', 'contest' );
    add_meta_box( 'contest-description', __('Description/Rules'), 'imgw_description_editor', 'contest' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'imgw_meta_boxes' );

function imgw_dates_metabox($object){

      wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
?>
<div>
<label>Starting Date</label>
<input type="date" name="contest-starting-date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-starting-date", true); ?>"> at <input type="time" name="contest-starting-time" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-starting-time", true); ?>">
<label>Ending Date</label>
<input type="date" name="contest-ending-date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-ending-date", true); ?>"> at <input type="time" name="contest-ending-time" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-ending-time", true); ?>">
</div>

<?php
} 

function imgw_description_editor($object){ ?>
<textarea name="contest-description" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter a description or rules..."><?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'contest-description', true); ?></textarea>
<?php    
}
function imgw_save_contest_meta( $post_id, $post ) {

    global $post;

  if($post->post_type == 'contest')
    return;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-description', $_POST['contest-description'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-starting-date', $_POST['contest-starting-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-starting-time', $_POST['contest-starting-time'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-ending-date', $_POST['contest-ending-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-ending-time', $_POST['contest-ending-time'] );

} // end save_meta_data

add_action('save_post', 'imgw_save_contest_meta', 10, 3);

function imgw_contest_content( $content ){

    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'contest'){
        $content = "[imgw-contest][/imgw-contest]";
        return $content;  

    }      

    wp_die('Hello!');

}

add_filter('the_content', 'imgw_contest_content');
```

Comment: `the_content` only in action when you are viewing post on front-end no changes will be made on DB or actual post content!

Comment: if you're going to override the post's content, just hide the field in your post type registration and output what you need on the front end via filters. I don't see any advantage to adding this complexity to the back end.

Comment: Also, your `wp_die()` isn't doing anything because you're using `return` before you get there.

Answer (score 0):

To update properties of a post in the database use [`wp_update_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

```
// Update post 37
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 37,
      'post_title'   => 'This is the post title.',
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Just beware of the possibility of an [infinite loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution_-_Infinite_loop) when updating a post.