# Why are my custom metaboxes not updating the post meta?

Tags: post-meta

It works fine when creating a new post, but nothing happens when I edit a post.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function imgw_save_contest_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    global $post;

    if( $post->post_type == 'contest' )
        return;

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-description', $_POST['contest-description'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-starting-date', $_POST['contest-starting-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-starting-time', $_POST['contest-starting-time'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-ending-date', $_POST['contest-ending-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-ending-time', $_POST['contest-ending-time'] );
} // end save_meta_data

add_action( 'save_post', 'imgw_save_contest_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You are skipping `update_post_meta` if `post_type` is `contest` by this code `if($post->post_type == 'contest')
    return;` Why ?

Comment: You open new question and its look like your code from here. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/221164/18731 is it the same code or not?

Comment: It's from the same plugin but it is a different issue.

Comment: @Sumit Yep, that was the problem.  forgot that return was there lol.